# ADS does not support table variables?

Tags: advantage-database-server

For example, in Transact-SQL, I can declare a table variable like this:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(  
    EmpID INT NOT NULL,  
    OldVacationHours INT,  
    NewVacationHours INT,  
    ModifiedDate datetime);
```

I'm using ADS 11. It looks like this version does not support table variables.

UPDATED

I looked at ADS 12, this version also does not support table variables.

Comment: No, ADS doesn't support table variables. The closest you can get is using a temp table with the `#tablename` syntax.

Comment: I agree. I looked at ADS 12, this version also does not support table variables.